# Ordering by two columns sorted by priority

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to show the result of the query below sorted by the priority.

```
mysql> select CouponId, CouponCode, DateAdded, Priority from Coupon where IsFeatured=1 and IsApproved=1 order by DateAdded desc limit 12;
+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------+
| CouponId | CouponCode   | DateAdded           | Priority |
+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------+
|    42699 | cc2          | 2013-09-12 14:54:39 |     NULL |
|    42698 | c1           | 2013-09-12 14:53:36 |     NULL |
|    42697 | cc2          | 2013-09-12 14:51:57 |     NULL |
|    42679 | GLMR20       | 2013-05-14 13:21:07 |        5 |
|    42678 | HKBAJAJ20    | 2013-05-14 12:35:31 |        1 |
|    42677 | SIPPER51     | 2013-05-14 12:11:36 |     NULL |
|    42654 | GL13MAYCHILL | 2013-05-14 07:09:08 |        7 |
|    41978 | POLARSPL     | 2013-05-03 13:31:32 |     NULL |
|    41958 | COMBO30      | 2013-05-03 12:16:53 |     NULL |
|    41357 | BRANDED60    | 2013-04-25 13:49:56 |     NULL |
|    41073 | PKCCR500     | 2013-04-22 11:10:27 |     NULL |
|    40794 | SWC15        | 2013-04-18 13:57:54 |     NULL |
+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I though another order by Priority desc would do it but it produces the same result

```
mysql> select CouponId, CouponCode, DateAdded, Priority from Coupon where IsFeatured=1 and IsApproved=1 order by DateAdded desc, Priority desc limit 12;
+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------+
| CouponId | CouponCode   | DateAdded           | Priority |
+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------+
|    42699 | cc2          | 2013-09-12 14:54:39 |     NULL |
|    42698 | c1           | 2013-09-12 14:53:36 |     NULL |
|    42697 | cc2          | 2013-09-12 14:51:57 |     NULL |
|    42679 | GLMR20       | 2013-05-14 13:21:07 |        5 |
|    42678 | HKBAJAJ20    | 2013-05-14 12:35:31 |        1 |
|    42677 | SIPPER51     | 2013-05-14 12:11:36 |     NULL |
|    42654 | GL13MAYCHILL | 2013-05-14 07:09:08 |        7 |
|    41978 | POLARSPL     | 2013-05-03 13:31:32 |     NULL |
|    41958 | COMBO30      | 2013-05-03 12:16:53 |     NULL |
|    41357 | BRANDED60    | 2013-04-25 13:49:56 |     NULL |
|    41073 | PKCCR500     | 2013-04-22 11:10:27 |     NULL |
|    40794 | SWC15        | 2013-04-18 13:57:54 |     NULL |
+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

How can I order the result of this query by Priority, so that the row with Priority 7 appears at top irrespective of its DateAdded?

I need the sort by DateAdded in the query to just pick the top 12 rows with regard to time and then sort them according to the priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select CouponId, CouponCode, DateAdded, Priority 
from
(
   select CouponId, CouponCode, DateAdded, Priority 
   from Coupon
   where IsFeatured=1 
   and IsApproved=1 
   order by DateAdded desc
   limit 12
) x
order by Priority desc
```

Comment: You need to name subqueries with an alias. I used `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to order by non nulls first (after Date Added):

```
SELECT CouponId, CouponCode, DateAdded, Priority 
FROM Coupon WHERE (IsFeatured = 1) and (IsApproved = 1) 
ORDER BY   DateAdded desc, Priority IS Null, Priority desc limit 12;
```